# How to show the count of each image as it is being scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Considering the images are in a `for` loop, I want to show the image number in a fixed position as it is being scrolled. Does anyone know how to do it? The solution for this will be of great help in my project.

```
 <style>
     #rightCol{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 82vh;
    }
    body{
        overflow:hidden;
    }
 </style>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9" style="padding:0; border:ridge; " id="rightCol">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_1.jpg') ?>" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_2.jpg') ?>" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_3.jpg') ?>" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_4.jpg') ?>" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_5.jpg') ?>" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_6.jpg') ?>" />
    <br>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your code does not appear scroll

Comment: You tagged jQuery... are you only looking for jQuery solutions?

Answer (score 0):

So, you wanna find the first image visible, and count that as your visible image.
With the variable `scroll_line` you can adjust how far the image should be inside the window to be counted as the current.

```js
$(document).scroll(scrolled)
$(document).ready(scrolled)

var scroll_line = 32;

function scrolled(){
 var images = $('.img-responsive') // get all images via classname
 for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
  var pos = images.eq(i).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop() // get absolute position of image regarding scroll
  if(pos>scroll_line){ // image is inside screen
   break // found image in screen, done
  }
 }
 var current_image = i;
 
 $('#image_number').html('Image Nr. '+current_image) // output image number (assuming your display has id 'image_number')
}
```

```css
#image_number{
  position: fixed;
  top: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image_number"></div>

<img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you will understand with the following code example :

```js
$(document).scroll(scroll)

function scroll(){
    var images = $('.img-responsive')
    
    for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
        var pos = images.eq(i).offset().top - $(document).scrollTop()
        if(pos>0){
            curr_img = i
            break
        }
    }
    var curr_img = i+1;

    $('#image_no').html('Number :'+curr_img) 
}
```

```css
img{
  max-width:50%;
}
#image_no{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  color:red;
  width: 100%;
background: white;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
     <div id="image_no">Number : 0</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 main_img_class" style="padding:0;margin-top: 7%;border:ridge; " id="rightCol">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fitzmuseum.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/1_0.jpg" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fitzmuseum.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/1_0.jpg" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fitzmuseum.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/1_0.jpg" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fitzmuseum.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/1_0.jpg" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fitzmuseum.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/1_0.jpg" />
    <br>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fitzmuseum.cam.ac.uk/sites/default/files/1_0.jpg" />
    <br>
    </div>
    </div>
```